# Node server returning only index.html don't load bundle.js or other js files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, webpack

Hello stackoverflow members,

this is my first question, so please be gentle.

Currently I've an Amazon-web-service(AWS) server which is runing of node.js.
I've copied the node.js file from AWS the example project for node.js.

```
////node.js
var port = process.env.PORT || 3666,
    http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    html = fs.readFileSync('index.html');

var log = function(entry) {
    fs.appendFileSync('/tmp/sample-app.log', new Date().toISOString() + ' - ' + entry + '\n');
};
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        var body = '';

        req.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        req.on('end', function() {
            if (req.url === '/') {
                log('Received message: ' + body);
            } else if (req.url = '/scheduled') {
                log('Received task ' + req.headers['x-aws-sqsd-taskname'] + ' scheduled at ' + req.headers['x-aws-sqsd-scheduled-at']);
            }

            res.writeHead(200, 'OK', {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            res.end();
        });
    } else {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.write(html);
        res.end();
    }
});

// Listen on port 3000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(port);

// Put a friendly message on the terminal
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:' + port + '/');
```

How I writed in the header I get only the index.html.
This is how it look it in the console

> bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token  <

If I open bundle.js in network tab(from chrome) there is only the code from the index.html

```
////index.html 
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="ger" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.6.7.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>test</h1>

<div ng-view></div>
<script>
            $(document).foundation();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[Node JS and Webpack Unexpected token <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260093)
Here had an other person the same problem(probably), but how far I've understand they've only recommended an other server application(Express)? 
But cause I use AWS I can only use node.js

It has nothing to do with the bundle.js this problem has any JavaScript file.

I've no experince with node.js, I only wish to load Javascript files.

A walkaround: I can use and load correctly http calls. But this is extrem time consuming. I need to load all Js files(even my modul Controller) on my AWS s3 bucket.

It's a single page application that has many custom Javascript files und modules.  [Here a screenshot from my directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJLUR.png)

I looking forward to your answers!

Comment: Post your HTML file.

Comment: `but how far I've understand they've only recommended an other server application(Express)? But cause I use AWS I can only use node.js` just FYI , Express is a node module, you can use express in any node application, wherever it is running, be it AWS, be it Heroku or your local machine.

Comment: This is a webpack error!!, your Node part & HTML are irrelevant. It's the building of bundle that's the problem.

Comment: @todarist can you access any other js files ? or css files ? if yes then check if bundle.js file path is correct.. this error also comes when path is not reachable.

Comment: I think this question is relevant here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260093/node-js-and-webpack-unexpected-token

Comment: @MBielski my HTML File is already in the post? You can search after "////index.html "

Comment: Your node server is written such that all requests , return index.html. So once first request is send and your server sends back index html, browser attempts to load localhost:3000/bundle.js from your node server. But instead of giving bundle js it will return index html

Comment: Hello @Keith how I say this is with any JavaScript file. I thought I could solve this problem wirh webpack but it's how every other Js file..

Comment: Hello @Subin "Node JS and Webpack Unexpected token < Here had an other person the same problem(probably), but how far I've understand they've only recommended an other server application(Express)? But cause I use AWS I can only use node.js" that is what I've writen do the link what you have posted. So and how can I load now my Js files?

Comment: @todarist1 this is the exact problem being discussed in that question.

Answer (score 2):

Your Node server is configured to only ever serve your `index.html` file.

Your `http.createServer` method implementation can be broken down into:

```
When a request comes in
  If it is a POST request
    Process the request
  else
    Serve index.html
```

So when a request is made for `bundle.js` you are serving `index.html`. As `bundle.js` is expected to be javascript, an error is thrown when the `<` token is read, as it is not a valid javascript token.

Solving this problem should be broken down to into several questions. You should start with setting up a working server locally - using something like [Express](http://expressjs.com/) can help simplify serving different files for different requests.

Comment: Exactly. Use Express to serve static content. Or you can write the logic yourself, For eg: if request url ends with .js or .css find and serve the file from your static folder(where you keep your bundle.js) if it is anything else serve index html