# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in dist/index.html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I am using webpack2 and react hot loader3 with express. I am getting an error of

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in dist/index.html

Here is my configuration file

**webpack.config.js**

```
const isDevelopment = process.argv.indexOf('--development') !== -1;

const VENDOR_LIBS = [
    'react', 'react-dom', 'redux', 'react-redux',
    'react-router', 'react-router-redux', 'lodash',
    'express',
];

const entryPath = path.join(__dirname, 'src/index.js');

const config = {
  entry: {
    bundle: isDevelopment ? [
                            'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
                            'react-hot-loader/patch',
                            entryPath
                          ] : entryPath,
    vendor: VENDOR_LIBS
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '',
    filename: isDevelopment ? '[name].js' : '[name].[chunkhash].js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          loader: 'css-loader'
        }),
        test: /\.css$/,
      },
      {
        use: ['babel-loader'],
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: { limit: 40000 }
          },
          'image-webpack-loader'
        ],
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff|woff2|eot|otf|ttf)$/,
      },
    ],
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
       'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: 'src/index.html',
      minify: {
        removeComments: false,
        collapseWhitespace: false,
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css'),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['vendor', 'manifest']
    }),
  ],
};
isDevelopment && config.plugins.push(
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
          output: {
            comments: false,
            screw_ie8: true
          },
        })
    );
module.exports = config;
```

**server.js**

```
const isDevelopment = process.argv.indexOf('--development') !== -1;

if (isDevelopment) {

  const webpack = require('webpack');
  const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');

  const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

  app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
    noInfo: true,
    hot: true,
    stats: {
      colors: true
    }
  }));

  app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));

} else {

  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/src/assets/'));
}

app.get('*', function (request, response) {

  response.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});

app.listen(port);

console.log(`server started on port: ${port}`);
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "pre-start": "webpack",
    "start-dev": "node server.js --development",
    "start-prod": "rimraf dist && webpack && node server.js --production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.2",
    "react-router": "^3.0.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.7",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "reselect": "^2.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.17.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.0.0-beta.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.26.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "next",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "beta",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "beta",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.15.0"
  }
}
```

Here is the screenshot of an error that is shown in console

[image]

What might be the cause for this error? Is it problem with htmlWebpackPlugin or extract-text-webpack-plugin?

**UPDATE**
using publicPath and manifest.hash.js my index.html of dist will be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Pogimon</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="manifest.79b84dc7d02a392424d5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/manifest.6dcd342a4568f6b57de6.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor.a79b5bc95a09216321bd.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/bundle.d03400470aaca7bf8a0d.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node JS and Webpack Unexpected token <](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260093/node-js-and-webpack-unexpected-token)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be hit by a common issue which appears in combination of react-router and browser-history, when the script urls in index.html are not absolute.

Because of relative script src, if you (or Webpack reload) happen to refresh the browser when your history is on a route, the browser will now try to load the scripts from your route's url, e.g. if the route is `/login` and a reload/refresh occurs, the browser will ask for `/login/manifest.<hash etc>.js` and your express will then return it index.html because there's a `*` route handler there :).

The fix is to change your scripts' src inside index.html to `/manifest.<hash etc>.js` to make it absolute. This will ensure they are served by the static module.

More details are available in this answer - [HtmlWebpackPlugin injects relative path files which breaks when loading non-root website paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620628/htmlwebpackplugin-injects-relative-path-files-which-breaks-when-loading-non-root).

Comment: you mean to say <script type="text/javasctipt" src="1cd45e1ea00c59a34ecb.js"></script> but this will be created by htmlwebpackplugin inside dist/index.html

Comment: You can use `output.publicPath = "/"` in webpack.config.js to address this. More details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620628/htmlwebpackplugin-injects-relative-path-files-which-breaks-when-loading-non-root

Comment: I have to use publicPath and also like in my first comment, right?

Comment: won't hash changes when i change the file, if i include it in src/index.html by hand?

Comment: You won't need to touch htmlwebpackplugin with this approach, so hashes and everything will work as expected. The plugin would simple prepend the value of publicPath to the inserted script refs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133616/discussion-between-apprentice-and-hazardous).