# Express/React app works locally but not on Heroku

Tags: javascript, express, heroku, webpack

**Update**

Okay, so I updated the `Procfile` to bundle my components together

**Procfile**

`web: npm run build-client && node server/index.js`

But now it takes such a long time for my app to load because bundling takes a long time. Is there a better way to do this? This is a horrible user experience

...
And if nothing else, is there a way to render a static page right away that says:

*Blame Heroku, not me*

**====== Original Context =======**

My application works correctly with `heroku local` & `localhost:8080`, my view fails to render on deployment `heroku open`. From the console, I get this error message:

`app.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

This particular bundle contains my React components. I used a codesplit with webpack to load in dependencies at different moments because I'm using a vr framework (aframe/three.js) on the front end and react. I don't understand why this is occurring if it works just fine locally.

**index.html**

*I have codesplit some JS modules by aframe/three components inside of `index.bundle`. And all of my react components are inside of `app.bundle`*

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Faceoff!</title>
  <script src="./commons.js"></script>
  <script src="./index.bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/v3.13.1/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
  <style> ... </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="./app.bundle.js" defer></script> 
</body>
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
'use strict'
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')

const extractCommons = new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'commons',
  filename: 'commons.js'
})

const config = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client'),
  entry: {
    index: './index.js',
    app: './app.jsx'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /jsx?$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client'),
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    extractCommons
  ]
};

module.exports = config
```

**index.js**

*The server-side code for the app. I have seen others catch their mistakes in this general location so I'll put this up for good measure.*

```
'use strict'
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

const production = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const port = production ? process.env.PORT : 8080;

var publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../public');

app.use(express.static(publicPath));

app.use('/', (req, res, send) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'index.html'))
})

app.listen(port, () => {
 console.log(`Virtual Reality Enabled On Port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260093/node-js-and-webpack-unexpected-token

Comment: Yes, but based on that answer, I don't see how serving my bundle is being affected. I am using Express to serve up my static files, which in this case, are located in my `public` directory. 

This line here does that for me: `app.use(express.static(publicPath));`

The app does function correctly and my view renders on localhost. And the absolute path is correct.

Comment: The explanation as to what that error message may mean is eye opening so thank you for sharing. Not there yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your npm script `build-client` builds your webpack bundle. Reading your webpack.config.js tells me that the bundles will be in a directory called public and all your file names will have .bundle.js as a suffix. So you should change your Procfile to `web: npm run build-client && node public/index.bundle.js`

Comment: Woah, I actually just figured that out as you were writing it, refresh the page and you'll see why I don't like this approach, but I can live with it if I must. This is definitely a solution that can works. You are absolutely correct about the Procfile part.